# Libreria Google Charts tipo Annotation Chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

Mi pregunta es como hacer siempre visibles los puntos de este tipo de gráfico proporcionado por la librería de gráficas de googles, como se observa en el enlace que dejo abajo, solo se muestran los puntos cuando se posa el ratón encima.

Decir que por motivos de diseño de mi proyecto, no puedo cambiar a otro tipo de gráfico .

Un saludo.

PD: el gráfico está al principio de la página, que no se porque se desplaza hasta el final.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart#events

Comment: el link que dejaste no permite intuir tu situación actual ni el resultado esperado. No hay un evento mouseover ni nada similar

Comment: Gracias por tomarte la molestia, no me había dado cuenta de que el enlace te desplaza al final de la página, y el gráfico sale al principio.

Comment: Se *desplaza* porque tiene la etiqueta `#events` al final de la URL. Pero ese no es el motivo por dejó en espera a la pregunta. Por favor revisa [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](/help/dont-ask) con la idea de generar un [mcve]